# Universal React.JS - Requiring Styles and Images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side, universal

Lately I've been dabbling with React and Webpack, and so far i've been loving it. Sure it took a lot of reading, looking at exemples, and trying some stuff out, but eventually, react itself as well as hot reloading my components grew on me and I'm pretty sure I want to continue that way.

For the past couple of days though I've been trying to make my pretty simple "application" (so far it's just a menu with a couple of sub components and react router to display a dummy page) render server side.

Here's my project's layout:

[image]

Here's what my webpack config looks like so far:

```
let path = require("path"),
    webpack = require("webpack"),
    autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "webpack-hot-middleware/client",
        "./client"
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/static/"
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, "common")
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                loader: "babel", 
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: __dirname
            },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass!postcss" },
            { test: /\.svg$/, loader: "file" }  
        ]
    },
    sassLoader: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "common", "scss")]
    },
    plugins: [        
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true),
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify( process.env.NODE_ENV || "development" )
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    postcss: [autoprefixer({remove: false})]
}
```

And, omitting the module requirements, my server:

```
// Initialize express server
const server = express();

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
server.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath }));
server.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

// Get the request
server.use((req, res) => {
    // Use React Router to match our request with our components
    const location = createLocation(req.url);
    match({routes, location}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error.message);
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
            res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
        } else if (renderProps) {
            res.send(renderFullPage(renderProps));
        } else {
            res.status(404).send("Not found");
        }
    })

});

function renderFullPage(renderProps) {
    let html = renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps}/>);
    return  `<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <title></title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="app">${html}</div>
                    <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
                </body>
                </html>
            `;
}

server.listen(3000);
```

Little React Router server-side specificities here but I can get my head around it.

Then came an issue with requiring styles inside a component. After a while I figured out this bit (thanks to a github issue thread):

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
    require("../scss/components/menu.scss");
    logo = require("../images/flowychart-logo-w.svg") ;
}
```

And along with it the fact that I still need to declare a router on my client, re-using the routes my server already uses:

```
// Need to implement the router on the client too
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router } from "react-router";
import createBrowserHistory from "history/lib/createBrowserHistory";
import routes from "../common/Routes";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router children={routes} history={history} />,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

And now there I am. My style is applied and everything works. I'm still no expert, but so far I kind of understand everything that's going on (which is the main reason why I'm not using an existing universal js / react boilerplate - actually understanding what's going on).

But now my next issue to solve is how to require my images inside my components.
With this setup, it actually does work, however I'm getting this warning:

```
Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the 
checksum was invalid. 
This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. 
React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
     (client) "><img class="logo" src="/static/31d8270
     (server) "><img class="logo" alt=""
```

And it makes sense, as you've seen in a previous code snippet, I actually set a logo variable when I'm in the browser environment, and I use that variable to set the src tag of my components. Sure enough on the server, no src attributes is then given, thus the error.

Now to my question:
Am i doing that style / image requirement right ? What am I missing to get rid of that warning ?

The one thing I love about that webpack / react association is how I can keep those dependencies close to the actual part of my UI that uses them. However the one thing I've found out was omitted from most of the tutorials out there was how to keep this sweetness working when rendering server side.
I'd be very grateful if you guys could give me some insight.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend webpack-isomorphic-tools as a solution here.

I have a section on how to import SVG's into React apps in an example project: https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego#importing-svgs

Here is the code that was required to turn my Universal React app into one that accepts SVG's : https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego/compare/svg

Answer (score 1):

There's at least two approaches you can take for this:

1. Try to de-webpackify your code to run in Node.
2. Compile your client code with Webpack using [target 'node'](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target).

The first option requires you to remove Webpack specific code such as `require.ensure / System.import` and teaching node your module resolution rules and how to convert non js assets into js. This is achievable with a few babel transformations and maybe modifications to the `NODE_PATH` however this approach does mean you're constantly chasing your tail, i.e. if you start using a new Webpack feature / loader / plugin you need to make sure you're able to support the equivalent functionality in Node.

The second approach is probably more practical as you can be sure that whichever Webpack features you're using will also work on the server. This is one way you may do it:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = [
    {
        target: 'web',
        entry: './client',
        output: {
            path: dist,
            filename: 'client.js'
        }
    }, {
        target: 'node',
        entry: './server',
        output: {
            path: dist,
            filename: 'server.js',
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
        }
    }
];
```

---

```
// client.js
renderToDom(MyApp, document.body);
```

---

```
// server.js
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(`
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
            <body>
                ${renderToString(MyApp)}`
                <script src="/dist/client.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    `);
}
```

---

```
// index.js
const serverRenderer = require('./dist/server');
server.use(serverRenderer);
server.listen(6060);
```